# the get title verifecation not identife by name on selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i tried to verifed the title if it's correct or not and it's stuck i take the acording to name but it's not work

**this is my code:**

```
      string Expecttitle = "Consular Department in Jerusalem";
      string actualValue = element.FindElement(By.Name("PageTitle")).Text;
      Assert.AreEqual(actualValue, Expecttitle);
```

**this is the html**

```
<h1 name="PageTitle" class="h2 reforma-medium xs-mb-15 lg-mb-20">Consular Department in Jerusalem</h1>
```

getting this error 
TestMethod1
   Source: UnitTest1.cs line 19
   Duration: 13.1 sec

Message: 
    Test method hw.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
    RemoteWebElement.FindElementByName(String name)
    <>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(ISearchContext context)
    By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
    RemoteWebElement.FindElement(By by)
    UnitTest1.TestMethod1() line 41

this text that i want to check 
[image]

Comment: What is the expected title value?  Or is it the `FindElement` that is failing?

Comment: You're finding the element from 'element' - what is that element you are finding from?  `driver.FindElement(By.Name("PageTitle")).Text;` should work where driver is your webdriver instance.

Comment: The make the question better: 1. Add the actual error you are getting. 2. show the code where the variable "element" is created. 3. Show a little bit more of the DOM (HTML)

Answer (score 0):

```
  string actualValue = element.FindElement(By.Name("PageTitle")).Text;
```

This searches for elements within the scope of `element` an earlier found element? It probably does not contain the `<h1>`.

You could debug by printing the innerHtml of `element` and see manual if it contains the Name you are trying to find:

```
Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Probably you want to search the whole page for the `By.Name()`, like:

```
  string actualValue = driver.FindElement(By.Name("PageTitle")).Text;
```

Comment: No, because the error " stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document " means you are using a WebElement reference which is not in the page at the time you try to use it. I cannot debug that without the full code and the webpage itself. Probably you use the "element." after you navigated to another page, or the page is dynamic and Selenium found it, but it is redrawn or gone when you try to use it. You could wrap it in a try/catch and find it again in the catch block. Research Stale Elements.